# Schema is not working when using collections organized with subdirectories in AstroJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, astrojs

I have the following structure in the *content* directory:

[image: astroJS data content collection]

As you observe, I've a top level "profesionales" directory and multiple second-level folders, each correspond to a certain category.

**The entries in each folder has the same JSON structure**. So, I created the corresponding schema (following this guide https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/#defining-a-collection-schema)

The schema of each entry looks like this:

```js
import {defineCollection, z} from 'astro:content';

const profesionalesCollection = defineCollection({
    type: 'data',
    schema: z.object({
        id: z.string(),
        nroMatricula: z.string(),
        nombre: z.string(),
        apellido: z.string(),
        textoMuestra: z.string(),
        especialidad: z.string(),
        urlPerfilImg: z.string(),
        email: z.string()
    })
});

export const collections = {
    'profesionales': profesionalesCollection
};
```

The problems is that I'm not getting TypeScript support while coding (autocomplete and type errors)

**I'd like to know how to get full TypeScript support when using subdirectories in a collection of type 'data' (json)**

Answer (score 0):

The solution was setting two entries (`strictNullChecks` and `allowJs`) to "true" in `compilerOptions` property at tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "extends": "astro/tsconfigs/base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

Also, let me remind you that **type support for any collection means describing the [data](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#data) property** of each [CollectionEntry](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#collection-entry-type)